# Creating a CI Build for in premise TFS 2015

Tags: tfs-2015

I create a new build definition using the Visual Studio template. In the part where I have to Save and Queue the build, I see this window below but I cannot see anything in Queue drop-down to select. How should I set this up? Looks like I am missing a step.

[image: TFS CI/CD]

Comment: Hi alltej, any update on this issue, did my reply helped to figure out it or gave a right direction?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks! It was a role configuration on the server so I was not able to see the Default queue/pool

Comment: done! i think it will also help if there was no queue available for a user account, there is some message/feedback in the popup. I find it difficult if the user/admin that built the TFS is also new and it might help if that default queue is available (by default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be some agent pools for you selecting under the queue drop.

First you could manually check if there are some agent pools under **Agent Queues--All Queues**

[image]

If there are, this may related to permissions. Double check if your account have enough related permission  such as **queue builds**. Make sure there is not any deny setting for your account and any group your account joined. In TFS, deny trumps allow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup up build agent, pool and queue.

[image]

**Here is a Microsoft introduction "How to configure Agents, Pools and Queues"**

> https://microsoft.github.io/almvm/labs/tfs/build/

Comment: understood but why drop down is blank?

Comment: It seems that you have no agent configured. You have to install agent and link them to a agent pool